# Как правильно создать sql-запрос, чтобы после запятой выводилось два знака?

Tags: sql

Использую sql developer, создаю запрос , как в учебнике написано `NAME_VARIABLE FLOAT(5, 2)`, но пишет ошибку - не правильный синтаксис. В документации написано -
 `FLOAT[(M,D)]` Атрибут `M` указывает количество выводимых пользователю знаков, а атрибут `D` - количество разрядов, следующих за десятичной точкой. Как быть ? И что ставить вместо `М`, если заранее я не знаю из скольки знаков будет состоять число ?

Comment: укажите тип БД пожалуйста...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. вы используете `sql developer` - сделаю предположение, что вы работаете с Oracle DB.

[Документация Oracle DB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020) утверждает, что `FLOAT([p])` принимает только один параметр - точность

Судя по вашему описанию вы имели ввиду `NUMBER(M,D)`:

```
NAME_VARIABLE NUMBER(5, 2)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Значит вот тут -
 https://www.site-do.ru/db/sql2.php лежит не точное описание

Comment: @YuriiS, вы не указали тип БД в вопросе. Увидев `sql developer`, я сделал вывод, что вы работаете с Oracle DB. По вашей ссылке описываются типы данных в MySQL - и там описание верное...

Comment: MaxU, понятно. Я учусь на базе Oracle DB, а описание читал по MySQL получается. Да, доучился , блин... )))

Comment: @YuriiS, это все от того, что MySQL теперь Oracle принадлежит :-D

Comment: MaxU, понятно, теперь буду знать ))